# How to make a button link to another html page in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am newbie with Rails and trying to make a simply Rails program and meet this problem.

I tried to make a button and I want to make this button link to another page.

As they said in the sample code, I wrote this code to make the button which named "location"

```
<li><a href="Location.html">Location</a></li>
```

Then, I wrote this code which I thought that could help the button "location" link to the page "About"

```
<%= link_to "About", pages_faction_path, class: "nav-link" %>
```

But it does not work. I also think about this code `<li><% link_to "Location", pages_location_path %></li>` , but it also not work. All I need is just to make this button link to the page.

Could you please give me some ideas to make this button work as well? Thank you very much.

Comment: So what is going wrong exactly?  Does the button show but not link to anything, is there an error on the page?  Please edit your question to include more about the specific issue that is happening, "doesn't work" isn't enough information to help you debug the issue.

Comment: Sorry for my shortcoming, when I wrote the 1st code, the button "Location" displayed, but when I clicked this button, I showed me the error that `No route matches [GET] "/pages/Location.html"`,  I just want to make the button "Location" link to the page Location so I wrote that code.

Comment: What is this `location.html`, is it a static page?

Comment: @Eyeslandic : yeah location.html is a static page, and I want to route to this page when I click to the button "About"

Comment: Do you have a route for that in `routes.rb`?

Comment: It sounds like you likely do not have a route in your config/routes.rb file to handle it and you probably do not have the view placed correctly either.  So read the error, it is giving you the answer, and make sure to edit your question to include that, don't add it in the comments.

Comment: Thanks friends, you are right, I do not have the route in my config/routes.rb and when I checked and rewrited it, everything done.

Answer (score -2):

you can use bootstrap `<a class="btn btn-primary" href="#" role="button">About</a>` for make button, then fill url into property href

Comment: This has nothing to do with the problem in the question